# Matching entire contents of a MySQL JSON column

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, database-design

How can I match the contents of an entire MySQL JSON column?

e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as matches 
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table.settings = '{ "color": "red", "location": "Australia", "flavour": "cheese" }'
```

Where settings is a `JSON` column type. The issue is when I store JSON in the field the keys are arranged differently.

the above will produce `matches === 0` when in actual fact there are many matches.

Comment: I know MySQL has JSON support now, but honestly it's still not a good idea to store serialised data (which is what JSON is) in a single column because extracting anything other than the most basic of information from the serialised column with just SQL is a massive pain in the neck.  Is it possible to refactor your DB schema so that this data can be stored in a more easily queried way (such as additional colour, location and flavour columns, or as keys and values in a dependant table)?

Comment: Nope - well yes - although the expense of adapting to a very frequently changing schemea is more costly

Comment: Maybe it'd be worthwhile considering a different non-SQL database instead then?  Something like Mongo or Couch?

Comment: Again the ops overhead is little worth the expense compared to having a real-world solution (see-below) integrated with our ACTUAL primary storage engine. Can you seriously imagine migrating an entire application simply because of one column on one table? THAT my friend is the essence of absurd.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to use `JSON_CONTAINS` function.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as matches 
FROM my_table
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(my_table.settings, '{ "color": "red", "location": "Australia", "flavour": "cheese" }')
```

This serves the use case where you are searching for JSON where you *do not know the structure* with JSON that *you do not know the structure* of

In Laravel Eloquent ORM you would:

```
MyTable::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(my_table.settings, ?)', json_encode($jsonString));
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use the [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as matches
FROM my_table
WHERE
JSON_EXTRACT(`settings` , '$.color') = "red"
AND JSON_EXTRACT(`settings` , '$.location') = "Australia"
AND JSON_EXTRACT(`setting`, '$.flavour') = "cheese";
```

I work with ORMs most of the time, so I might confuse some backticks and quotes, but you get the idea I hope!

Comment: The issue with this approach is that we need to know the contents of the json in advanced...

Comment: How do you plan to match an entire column of json is you don't know what you are going to match? Maybe I misunderstood your question, but my answer solves your code example.

Comment: e.g. I have JSON in a variable that I do not know the structure of. Im searching in a column of JSON I do not know the structure of

Comment: Sorry but you're not making any sense. If you have JSON in a variable, you by definition know its structure: `json_decode()`. The whole point of using `JSON_EXTRACT` is that you don't need to know the structure of the JSON in the database. You just match keys and values and let the database do its thing.

Comment: Glad you solved it in a way it works for you! Even though I still don't understand why my answer was problematic, but whatever. It works now :)

Comment: :-) was more to do with matching entire contents. To parse each field when i dont know the structure by extracting the contents would be excessive. Sending you a point, thanks for your effort